# PHP Doctrine with MSSQL: Incorrect syntax near &#039;:&#039;

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine

I am working on a Symfony 4 project with a MSSQL server (not optimal no, but corporate decision).

We are experiencing an issue when we use named variables.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near &#039;:&#039;.
```

ex:

```
$query->where("status = :status");
```

we apply the values with setParameter()

```
$query->setParameter('status', $status);
```

We receive a syntax error. I have attempted to store quotes with the variable itself to make sure that is not the case, however it returns the same error. If I replace the named variables with ex: 'ACTIVE' it works as expected. I have also printed the sql with getSQL() and tested this directly in SQL Management Studio, this works fine also.

Debugging the statement is rough, and I am considering if we need to make a connection wrapper class and manipulate in order to support MSSQL, but before going to that extend, maybe some of you guys have an idea?

Full error response:

```
An exception occurred while executing &#039;SELECT U.CIID AS ciid, U.USERID as userid, U.FIRSTNAME as firstname, U.MIDDLENAME as middlename, U.LASTNAME as lastname, ACI.emailid as email, U.JOBTITLE as position, ACI.landline as phone_local, ACI.mobile as phone_mobile, P.ATTRIBUTE_1801 as phone_cisco FROM SDUSER U INNER JOIN AaaUser AU ON U.USERID=AU.USER_ID INNER JOIN People P ON U.CIID=P.CIID INNER JOIN AaaUserContactInfo AUCI ON AU.USER_ID=AUCI.USER_ID INNER JOIN AaaContactInfo ACI ON AUCI.CONTACTINFO_ID=ACI.CONTACTINFO_ID WHERE U.STATUS=:status&#039;:

SQLSTATE [42000, 102]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near &#039;:&#039;.
SQLSTATE [42000, 8180]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (500 Internal Server Error)
```

As you can see, it looks like the named parameters is forcing a wrap of quotes of the entire sql that mssql cannot accept.

MSSQL 2012
PHP 7.1.3
Symfony 4
Doctrine 2

Comment: I believe the messed up quotes are just an encoding problem in your console. If you look closely, the error message actually quotes the colon (":") It seems that somehow it doesn't recognize the parameter correctly

Comment: Hi Emanuel, I am not running through a console. I agree it might be because the parameter might but be recognized. However I've followed examples and my code works on mariadb and postgresql, it is solely an issue when switching to mssql

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to put this code below:

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, mssql.charset is set to UTF-8 already